# free() : random error in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, free

I try to code ls command in C but i have a problem with -R option.

Output :

```
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/es5-ext/array/of:
implement.js
index.js
is-implemented.js
shim.js
ft_ls(61021,0x7fffc25583c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fedfd273700: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    61021 abort      ./ft_ls -R /
```

Ok know my recursive function :

```
static void upper_r_option(t_opt *option, char *dirname)
{
    char    **order;
    char    *path;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    order = ft_get_order(dirname, option);
    if (option->l)
        ft_getdata(order, dirname);
    else
        ft_puttab(order);
    while (order[i])
    {
        path = upper_r_checker(order[i], dirname);
        if (path != NULL)
        {
            upper_r_option(option, path);
            free(path);
        }
        i++;
    }
    ft_free_tab(order);
    ft_putstr("FREE : OK\n");
    return ;
}
```

My error is at the end of my recursive function in ft_free_tab.
What I do not understand is why i'm able to free sometime and randomly i can't.
When i launch my program "./ft_ls -R /" i see some "FREE : OK" before the error.

My ft_free_tab :

```
void    ft_free_tab(char **tab)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    if (tab[1] == NULL)
        free(tab);
    else if (tab != NULL)
    {
        while (tab[i])
        {
            free(tab[i]);
            i++;
        }
        free(tab);
    }
}
```

### **EDIT :**

I trying to debug this but something wrong.

Output :

```
This NULL = LICENSE


My order after R =
LICENSE
inherits.js
inherits_browser.js
package.json


Path strdup : 0x7f8218700640
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/inherits
Path in strjoin : 0x7f8218700640
YOPath strjoin1 : 0x7f8218701740
==========================

/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/inherits/
Path in strjoin : 0x7f8218701740
ft_ls(17078,0x7fffac1623c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8218700690: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    17078 abort      ./ft_ls -R /
```

This error is in upper_r_checker, in ft_str_fjoin. I tried to free the old path but i can't.

upper_r_option & upper_r_checker :

```
static char *upper_r_checker(char *this, char *dirname)
{
    char    *path;

    path = ft_strdup(dirname);
    printf("Path strdup : %p\n", path);
    if (!ft_issame(path, "/"))
        path = ft_str_fjoin(path, "/", 1);
    printf("Path strjoin1 : %p\n", path);
    ft_putstr("==========================\n\n");
    path = ft_str_fjoin(path, this, 1);
    ft_putstr("==========================\n\n");
    if (ft_type(path) == 'd' && !ft_issame(this, ".") &&
    !ft_issame(this, "..") && ft_error(path, 1))
    {
        ft_putchar('\n');
        ft_putstr(path);
        ft_putstr(":\n");
        ft_putstr("\nThis = ");
        ft_putstr(this);
        ft_putstr("\n\n");
        return (path);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putstr("\nThis NULL = ");
        ft_putstr(this);
        ft_putstr("\n\n");
        if (path != NULL)
            free(path);
        return (NULL);
    }
}

static void upper_r_option(t_opt *option, char *dirname)
{
    char    **order;
    char    *path;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    order = ft_get_order(dirname, option);
    if (option->l)
        ft_getdata(order, dirname);
    else
        ft_puttab(order);
    while (order[i])
    {
        path = upper_r_checker(order[i], dirname);
        if (path != NULL)
        {
            upper_r_option(option, path);
            free(path);
        }
        ft_putstr("\nMy order after R = \n");
        ft_puttab(order);
        ft_putstr("\n\n");
        i++;
    }
    ft_free_tab(order);
    return ;
}
```

ft_str_fjoin :

```
char    *ft_str_fjoin(char *s1, char *s2, int i)
{
    char    *fraiche;
    int     len;

    if (s1 == NULL || s2 == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    len = (ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1);
    fraiche = ft_memalloc(len);
    if (fraiche == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    ft_strcat(fraiche, s1);
    ft_strcat(fraiche, s2);
    fraiche[len] = '\0';
    if (i == 1)
    {
        ft_putstr(s1);
        ft_putchar('\n');
        printf("Path in strjoin : %p\n", s1);
        free(s1);
        ft_putstr("YO");
    }
    if (i == 2)
        free(s2);
    if (i == 3)
    {
        free(s1);
        free(s2);
    }
    return (fraiche);
}
```

Why can't free 0x7f8218701740 (Cf.Output) ?

Comment: `char  **order;` shadows a function argument. Your compiler should warn you about this. Also:what is the reason for these functions to return void?

Comment: @wildplasser I just edited my code to remove order argument. These functions return void because i just need to print informations or free and don't need to get more.

Comment: `while (order[i])` and `while (tab[i])` : this is why for() loops exist.

Comment: I know but i can't use for() it's forbidden function for this school project x)

Comment: Maybe one-letter identifiers should be forbidden, instead!

Comment: @wildplasser Edited

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
    if (tab[1] == NULL)    // this is digit '1'
```

should be

```
    if (tab[i] == NULL)     // this is variable 'i'
```

---

`tab` is apparently a null-terminated array of pointers to strings. The last element is null and indicates the end of the array. The function is never called with `tab` itself being null. The function can be simplified and condensed to:

```
void ft_free_tab(char **tab)
{
    int i= 0;
    while (tab[i]) free(tab[i++]);
    free(tab);
}
```

Comment: if (tab[1] == NULL)  is here because if tab = {"I'm a string", NULL} i just need to free tab and not element one by one.

If i don't have this line i will free tab twice.

Comment: You still have to free `tab[0]` and you won't free `tab` twice. Try it.